# Memory Leak in Progress 4GL Proxy Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, progress-4gl

Progress Version: 10.0B05.32

A few years ago, we used the Progress Proxy Generator to generate .NET assemblies that would allow us to connect C# code to our appserver processes. When developing this application we noticed a memory leak in the generated assemblies. After contacting Progress, we were provided with hotfix #32 for version 10.0B05. This hotfix corrected the memory leak problem and everything has been working fine.

Skip ahead to today, where we recently installed .NET 4.0 on several of servers running these generated assemblies. After updating to .NET 4.0 - it appears that the memory leak is back.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Is anyone aware of a hotfix that's available to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.0B is "retired" now (actually it was retired in March of 2006) so it is unlikely that there is a hotfix available or planned for such an issue.

You will likely be encouraged to upgrade to 10.2B which is the current active release.  The issue may already be fixed there or, if not, you should be able to get it addressed before OE11 is released (probably year-end).